# How to set Hibernate with sqlserver&jtds driver in Netbeans

Tags: java, hibernate, netbeans, jtds

I am trying to set up Netbeans to work with Hibernate using jtds driver to connect to SQLSERVER 2008.

The sqlserver 2008 is installed localy, no username or password.

This is hibernate.cfg:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
  <session-factory>
    <property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property>
    <property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</property>
    <property name="hibernate.query.factory_class">org.hibernate.hql.classic.ClassicQueryTranslatorFactory</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://localhost:2545/MyDB</property>
  </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

When I try to setup Hibernate reverse engineering file with Hibernate reverse engineering wizard, I get the following error:

> Unable to connect. Cannot establish a connection to
>   jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://localhost:2545/MyDB using
>   net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver (I/O Error: SSO Failed: Native SSPI
>   library not loaded. Check the java.library.path system property.).

I have ntlmauth.dll in WINDOWS\system32.

Comment: Have you arrived at any solution for this? The Reverse Engineering Wizard does nothing when using the jTDS driver, and works fine with the MS driver.

Answer (score 0):

`jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://localhost:2545/MyDB` appears to be an incomplete JDBC URL for the jTDS driver.

Going by the [jTDS FAQ](http://jtds.sourceforge.net/faq.html), you'll need to specify the `username` and `password` properties as well. Also, since you appear to be using integrated Windows authentication in MS SQL Server 2008, you would also need to set the `domain` property.

Note that, the `username` and `password` values will have to be provided unless you install the jTDS SSO library i.e. ntlmauth.dll; since you already have it in your PATH, you'll need to specify the `domain` property to login as the currently logged in user on the workstation.

Comment: nope, jtds work fine if i try to connect without hibirnate: Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(
                    "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://localhost:2545/MyDB"))